# displaylist of children in parent model one-to-many

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship, displaylist

I am learning django admin, i have to models with a one-to-many relation between them.
I got something like Manufacturer model where i can add different car manufacturers, and Car model for adding cars. In my django admin page i want to be able to display_list of all cars manfuctred by say manufacturer1 when i click on manufacturer1 entry.

I have found a trick by using Inline model in manufacturer admin model, the problem is that it loads every entry in the database and it takes some time as it's a big table.

Is there any method else to do that or do i have to create a new template  ?

**EDIT:** 
The goal is not to load every Car that is FK to Manufacturer1 like with InlineModelAdmin but to get the same display as with display_list with results split in pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

The easiest approach is to look at the relationship in reverse. Instead of going to a manufacturer change form and seeing all their cars. Go to the cars changelist and filter by manufacturer. You'll have to set the `list_filter` attribute on the car `ModelAdmin` to include manufacturer.

Option two, is going to be a huge pain, but you can override `change_view` on the manufacturer `ModelAdmin` to add the list of that manufacturer's cars to `extra_context`. Then, you'll have to override the admin template at 'templates/admin/yourapp/manufacturer/change_form.html'. You can then add to that template to produce the kind of list you're looking for using the list of cars you passed into `extra_context`, drawing on 'django/contrib/admin/templates/change_list.html' for inspiration.

Give the [Django docs on the Admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) a good thorough read. There's actually a wealth of info in there.

Comment: I like the list_filter idea !

Answer (score 2):

Answer for your updated question:

the way to do it could be by using [`ProxyModels`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) and overriding `ModelAdmin.queryset`

You extend the `Car` model via `FordCar`, `GMCar` and use `proxy=True` in the `Meta` class, for both those.

Then you can register seperate admins for each of `FordCar` and `GMCar` and override the queryset method in each of those ModelAdmin to filter for the respective manufacturer.

Ex:

```
class FordCarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    list_display = fields = ['name','model','engine']

    def queryset(self,request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(manufacturer__name='Ford')

admin.site.register(FordCar,FordCarAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanx for your example i did not know about proxy models, however i will not be able to create new Manufacturers dynamically if i have to create the ModelAdmin of each brand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any hack. Django admin displays only Cars that have a FK to Manufacturer1, when you select Manufacturer1, as long as you have used the [InlineModelAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) right and as intended.

Comment: Yes, you are right but whit InlineModelAdmin it loads all the Cars that have Fk to Manufacturer1 however the display_list split them in pages which is very convenient for huge entries